# Boost result by specified search term on top

Tags: solr

I'm using apache solr 3.1 with drupal

How can boost result on top which is specified in search field?

Example in search field, if user enters **continuing**, solr shows the document which have **Continuity** on top and the one with **continuing** below, i want to show the one with **continuing** above than the **Continuity**

http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=continuing&qf=title&fl=title%20score&bq=title:continuing^10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have stemmer in the filter chains, due to which continuing and Continuity and mapped to the same root and would be treated equal.

you want want to check for the stemmer you are using and want to get one depending upon your needs. The default porter stemmer is very agressive, and you may want an less agressive options.

Solr does not currently boost the exact match higher than the other terms which generated the same root.
One option would be to have two fields in your schema.
Stemmed (title_stemmed) and a Non Stemmed version (title - without the stemming filter)

example -

schema.xml -

```
<!-- Without Porter Stemmer -->
<fieldType name="text_non_stemmed" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<!-- With Porter Stemmer -->
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="false" omitNorms="false"/>    
<field name="title_non_stemmed" type="text_non_stemmed" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="false" omitNorms="false"/>

<copyField source="title" dest="title_non_stemmed"/>
```

you can weight the fields -

solrconfig.xml - modify the default request handler

```
<requestHandler name="search" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <str name="defType">dismax</str>
   <str name="qf">
      title_non_stemmed^1 title^0.8
   </str>
   <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
   <str name="rows">10</str>
   <str name="fl">*,score</str>
 </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

so that the exact match produces more score than the non exact matches and appears higher.

URL -

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=continuing
```

Comment: Thanks patil I just added <field name="title_unstem" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="false" omitNorms="false"/> and <copyField source="title" dest="title_unstem"/> but it is giving me the same reult plz help

Comment: your field type seems to be same "text". have edited the answer with an example.

Comment: also you might need to rebuild solr's index

Comment: <!-- non stemmed field --> 
<fieldType name="non_stemmed_text" class="solr.TextField">
<analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer"/></fieldType>  i have added this but i cannot sort on query time   http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=continuing%20&fl=title%20title_unstem%20score&qf=title_unstem^2%20title^1

Comment: not sure i got your comment. Modified the answer with the complete configuration.